# Strom must declare exactly one stream form last bolt in LinearDRPCTopology?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm, topology

I want to my data output to a `kafka` queue, so I write the `topology` as follow:

```
LinearDRPCTopologyBuilder builder = new LinearDRPCTopologyBuilder("xx");
builder.addBolt(new JdEntryParseBolt(config), 2);
builder.addBolt(new JdCrawlerBolt(config), 2).shuffleGrouping();
builder.addBolt(new JdParseBolt(config), 2).shuffleGrouping();
builder.addBolt(new KafkaBolt<String, Integer>(), 2).shuffleGrouping();

Config conf = new Config();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("metadata.broker.list", "127.0.0.1:9092");
map.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
conf.put("topic", "jdQueryCrawler");
conf.setMaxTaskParallelism(10);

LocalDRPC drpc = new LocalDRPC();
LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
cluster.submitTopology("xx-drpc", conf, builder.createLocalTopology(drpc));
```

when I submit the topology, it returns:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Must declare exactly one stream from last bolt in LinearDRPCTopology
            at backtype.storm.drpc.LinearDRPCTopologyBuilder.createTopology(LinearDRPCTopologyBuilder.java:152) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
            at backtype.storm.drpc.LinearDRPCTopologyBuilder.createLocalTopology(LinearDRPCTopologyBuilder.java:87) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
            at com.ipin.jd.process.topology.TestCrawlerDrpc.main(TestCrawlerDrpc.java:58) ~[test-classes/:na]
```

What does "exactly one stream from last bolt in LinearDRPC" mean? I do not add more than one stream.

Comment: Well, in your case it means you have to have an output stream from your topology (exactly two fields, the first should be the request id, and the second should be the result), but the topology ends with `KafkaBolt` without defined output stream